# Let C= [a b; b a]. Show that [1; 1] and [1; -1] are eigenvectors of C. What are corresponding eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let C= [a b; b a]. Show that [1; 1] and [1; -1] are eigenvectors of C. What are corresponding eigenvalues?

I am unsure on how to do this problem.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried doing (C-L*In)*(vector) and set equal to zero. Also I tried to find lambda by doing the det(L*In-C)=) and got L^2-2aL+a^2-b^2=0

Comment: Why? All you have to do is to multiply $C$ by $(1,1)$ and by $(1,-1)$.

Comment: then how do i find the corresponding eigenvalues?

Comment: In both cases, the result of the multiplication will be a scalar $\lambda$ times the original vector. Those $\lambda$'s are the eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we have to prove that

$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\ \ \ 1\\-1\end{bmatrix}=\lambda_1\begin{bmatrix}\ \ \ 1\\-1\end{bmatrix}\tag 1$$
and that 
$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\  1\\1\end{bmatrix}=\lambda_2\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}\tag 2$$
where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the eigenvalues of $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\b&a\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

So, calculate the eigenvalues. The characteristic equation is

$$(a-\lambda)^2-b^2=0$$

and its solutions are

$$\lambda_{1,2}=a\pm b.$$

You can check that $(1)$ and $(2)$ hold.